# Write output of file to a .csv

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write some basic script to list and write a listing of Autocad files with .dwg files to a .csv file, which I will later import into Excel.

I've been working at this for about 2 weeks. It's just a simple script, but it's killin' me. I'm on PYTHON 2.7 with IDLE and WINDOWS 10.

```
import os, glob, sys
###
###
###We're changing the Current Working Directory to this dir using the 
###os.chdir command

os.chdir(r'h:\\09- DISTRIBUTION\engineer\drft-tmp\355-plg1\EWR 195 - 6018 
Panel Repl\PG1 6018')

###Now we're using glob to find files with .dwg extension
###and we're printing to the IDLE SHELL, which is nice, but I don't want 
this
###HOWEVER, I want to print to a .csv file

files = glob.glob('*.dwg')
for file in glob.glob("*.dwg"):
print(file)



###Let's create a file for the text file

f = open("ListDWG1.txt", "w+")
myfile = open(r'h:\\09- DISTRIBUTION\engineer\drft-tmp\355-plg1\EWR 195 - 
6018 Panel Repl\PG1 6018')

###I'm stuck at this point. How do I get the .csv file created?
###How are we to write a file in .csv format
###So, let's use the for command to loop through the contents of this cwd
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better import csv, a built-in python module for managing *.csv files.
It has writer and reader functions and also a Dict parser for a better use of the data when reading.

Look at this: https://realpython.com/python-csv/

The steps for writing are:

```
with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
    employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    employee_writer.writerow(['John Smith', 'Accounting', 'November'])
    employee_writer.writerow(['Erica Meyers', 'IT', 'March'])
```

And for reading:

```
import csv

with open('employee_birthday.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print("Column names are", ", ".join(row))
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(row[0], "works in the", row[1], "department, and was born in", row[2])
            line_count += 1
    print("Processed", line_count, "lines.")
```

You can adapt this code to your needs

Comment: The IDE is not relevant to this sort of problem.  Anyway, import the csv module and read its chapter in the library reverence, plus other guides.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, I've added the .csv module to my code. I have been researching the reference to print the console, but no go. Here is what I've added:`with open('dwg_list.csv', 'files') as dwg_list
dwg_write = csv.writer(file_name, delimeter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
dwg_write.writerow(['{}\t'.format(elem))]))` this gets my dwg_list file created, but not populated. I think the | is what's messing me up

Comment: I´ve added some code from the link I shared before.